# Change default bitmap in CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I find solution [Setter.TargetName does not work against an element from the BasedOn setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821150/setter-targetname-does-not-work-against-an-element-from-the-basedon-setting).
But I do not understand how prement him to me.
I have a class:

```
public class MyCheckBox: CheckBox
{
  public bool DefaultValue
  {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(DefaultValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DefaultValueProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultValueProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultValue", typeof(bool), typeof(MyCheckBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));


  protected override void OnToggle()
  {
    this.IsChecked = this.IsChecked == null ? !DefaultValue : this.IsChecked.Value ? false : true;
  }
}
```

and XAML

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Imaging:BitmapImage x:Key="CheckBoxStatusSource" UriSource="FalseIfNull.png"/> <!-- icon if [IsChecked] is [null] -->
  </Style.Resources>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Image x:Name="CheckBoxStatus" Source="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStatusSource}"/>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckBoxStatus" Property="Source" Value="b.png"/><!-- icon if [IsChecked] is [true] -->
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckBoxStatus" Property="Source" Value="c.png"/><!-- icon if [IsChecked] is [false] -->
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type My:MyCheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="DefaultValue" Value="true">
      <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!This need change [UriSource] in [CheckBoxStatusSource] to "TrueIfNull.png"!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Perhaps there is another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to extend `CheckBox` for other reasons, what you're trying to do here can be done with Attached Properties too, and it would allow you to have one single `Style` for all your CheckBoxes.

```
public static class CheckBoxExtensions
{
    public static void SetDefaultValue(CheckBox element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(DefaultValueProperty, value);
    }
    public static bool GetDefaultValue(CheckBox element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(DefaultValueProperty);
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DefaultValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DefaultValue", typeof(bool), typeof(CheckBoxExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

This property is now available for you to use in any `CheckBox` in your solution, and in any Style and Template you use for your CheckBoxes. In this case...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Imaging:BitmapImage x:Key="CheckBoxStatusSourceFalse" UriSource="FalseIfNull.png"/> <!-- icon if [IsChecked] is [null] and [DefaultValue] is [false] -->
    <Imaging:BitmapImage x:Key="CheckBoxStatusSourceTrue" UriSource="TrueIfNull.png"/> <!-- icon if [IsChecked] is [null] and [DefaultValue] is [true] -->
  </Style.Resources>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Image x:Name="CheckBoxStatus" Source="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStatusSourceFalse}"/>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="local:CheckBoxExtensions.DefaultValue" Value="True" />
              <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="CheckBoxStatus" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStatusSourceFalse}"/>
          </MultiTrigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckBoxStatus" Property="Source" Value="b.png"/><!-- icon if [IsChecked] is [true] -->
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckBoxStatus" Property="Source" Value="c.png"/><!-- icon if [IsChecked] is [false] -->
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**EDIT:** Even if you still need to extend `CheckBox`, this Style would work for both regular `CheckBox` and your `MyCheckBox` implementation. Just create another Style that's based on this one.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type My:MyCheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
    ...
</Style>
```

And if you want to access the `DefaultValue` property from code-behind, you can do it this way:

```
CheckBoxExtensions.SetDefaultValue(checkBox, true);
bool defaultValue = CheckBoxExtensions.GetDefaultValue(checkBox);
```

Comment: but i lost `protected override void OnToggle()` :(

Comment: You can keep your `MyCheckBox`, this Style will work for them too. And you can set `DefaultValue` in C# code. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.